# How can I make my Mac Mini start headless?

Tags: boot, mac-mini, uefi

My Mac mini doesn't boot without a monitor connected to it. As I've read in various forums on the internet, Mac OS X lets the Mac Mini boot without an attached monitor if SSH is turned on. Obviously, there's a setting in the EFI somewhere.

Is it possible to apply this setting in Linux as well?

Comment: Even though I answered the question myself, I'm very much interested in a software solution rather than attaching a dummy connector.

Comment: If there is a software solution, it's most likely going to be in EFI, as you posited in your question. You might be better off asking on SuperUser as it's not really an issue with Ubuntu. Though my limited reading on the subject suggests that your answer below is probably the way to go.

Comment: If you want other answers but your own, then don't accept your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to buy dummy adapters, which tell the computer that there's a monitor connected.

They are quite easy to make oneself. Just use a DVI-I --> VGA adapter and connect the 2nd to the 7th pin using a 75 Ω resistor.

Comment: Or just plug the resistor between C2 and C5 in the DVI port directly without an adapter. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/352101/40801

Answer (score 2):

The bug is in Bootcamp. If you install `grub-efi` and enable it as the primary bootloader, you ran run Linux without any monitor attached.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that by using the [nvram](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/nvram.8.html) command under OS X, you can poke in a value that tells it to start without a monitor.  I don't know what that option would be.   `nvram -p` might give you a clue.

Comment: Can I also do that in Ubuntu?

Comment: I don't know.  It's possible you can get at it from the EFI shell?